# C++ Why I can't use the loop: while(fin>>x) for twice

Tags: c++, file, loops, io

I have some question about file **I/O in c++**.
When I use `while(fin>>x`) for twice in my program and `cout` two times, only the first time will display on my screen.

And my **test.txt** is:

```
I like eat banana
I like eat apple
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("test.txt");
  if(fin.fail()){
    cout<<"Error!"<<endl;
    exit(1);
  }
      else{
    int i=0,j=0;
    string x,y,a[20],b[20];
    while(fin>>x){
    a[i]=x;
    i++;
    }
    fin.
    while(fin>>y){
    b[j]=y;
    j++;
    }
for(int q=0;q<20;q++){
cout<<a[q]<<" ";
}
for(int w=0;w<20;w++){
cout<<b[w]<<" ";
}
  }
  fin.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post code and output as plaint text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Could you copy paste your code in the message?

Answer (score 2):

The reason making `fin >> x` return false (and exiting the first loop) still exists when you write `fin >> y` right afterwards. Hence, once `fin >> x`-loop is left, `fin >> y`-loop will not be entered.